# No PHP o date() pega hora do servidor ou do usuário?

Tags: php, data

Estou com uma dúvida sobre o `date`, ele pega a hora do servidor onde o meu site se encontra ou da máquina que o usuário esta acessando?

Estou dando uma olhada no Manual do PHP mas não consegui descobrir qual método local ele se refere: máquina ou usuário.

Comment: Segundo a página [PHP 5 Date and Time](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp):  *PHP date() function will return the current date/time of the server!*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ele se refere a data do servidor. Para ajustar a uma data específica e correta, use a função **date_default_timezone_set**, um exemplo de funcionamento com o horário de São Paulo

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
?>
```

Para ver a lista de `timezones` veja na [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php)

**ps:** sempre coloque essa linha no início do seu código PHP

Comment: Sim, sempre utilizo, mas era uma duvida que tinha que tira da cabeça, rs.

Comment: Estava me confundindo com o javascript...

Comment: rsrs, acontece. Se pegasse do usuário iria ser uma confussão quando você usar a data para ser gravada no seu banco de dados. Por exemplo, você quer saber que horário o usuário logou no sistema, no seu banco iria estar 13h30, mas ainda são 10h15 da manhã, então iria confundir tudo.

Comment: Estou gravando pra analisar a entrada de usuários no site cansei do google analytic... ia ser uma loucura total...

Comment: Então sempre ajuste o horário com a função citada. Pelo menos você terá um controle mais específico dos horários.

Answer (score 4):

> Estou com uma dúvida sobre o date, ele pega a hora do servidor onde o
>   meu site se encontra ou da máquina que o usuário esta acessando?

A classe ou a função [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)/[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) obtém a informação(data ou hora) do servidor que o php está instalado e não da máquina do usuário.

O horário pode ser definido através do [timezone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) que é fuso horário de um país ou região, horário de Brasília é o (GMT/UTC -3) três horas de atraso comparado ao horário de greenwitch.

Definir o fuso horário é boa ideia porque evite o seguinte erro:

> It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use
>   the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function.

Isso pode ser feito de duas maneiras a primeira é atribuir um timezone válido no php.ini essa configuração será válida para todo o servidor.
A linha baixo deve ser modificada(após a alteração reinicie o servidor):

```
date.timezone = America/Sao_Paulo
```

O segundo método é usar a função [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) uma vez chamada ela aplica-se somente ao script.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

[Exemplo - ideon](http://ideone.com/2tFAHx)

[Lista dos times zones válidos](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: Se eu utilizar ( date_default_timezone_set ("America/Sao_Paulo"); ) podera definir qual horario quero que o date busque ?

Comment: Isso define o 'relogio' que o servidor irá trabalhar que no caso é 3 horas atrasado comparado ao greenwitch

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o [`timezone`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) pra que ele pegue o horário que vc quer:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

Também é possível definir mais especificamente:

```
// set default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); // CDT

$info = getdate();
$date = $info['mday'];
$month = $info['mon'];
$year = $info['year'];
$hour = $info['hours'];
$min = $info['minutes'];
$sec = $info['seconds'];

$current_date = "$date/$month/$year == $hour:$min:$sec";
```

Veja mais  [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6621656/4734177).